# How to use Hive without hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am a new to NoSQL solutions and want to play with Hive. But installing HDFS/Hadoop takes a lot of resources and time (maybe without experience but I got no time to do this).

Are there ways to install and use Hive on a local machine without HDFS/Hadoop?

Comment: You mean HDFS? Hadoop is an eco-system, Hive, is part of Hadoop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

yes you can run hive without hadoop 
1.create your warehouse on your local system 
2. give default fs as file:///
 than you can run hive in local mode with out hadoop installation

In Hive-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?> 
<configuration>
      <property>
         <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name> 
         <value>false</value> 
      </property> 
     <property> 
      <!-- this should eventually be deprecated since the metastore should supply this --> 
        <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name> 
        <value>file:///tmp</value>
        <description></description> 
     </property>
     <property> 
        <name>fs.default.name</name> 
        <value>file:///tmp</value> 
     </property> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: put these configurations inside your hive-site.xml <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
  <!--  this should eventually be deprecated since the metastore should supply this -->
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>file:///tmp</value>
<description></description>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>file:///tmp</value>
</property>
</configuration>

Comment: To be precise, it means running Hive without HDFS from a hadoop cluster, it still need jars from hadoop-core in CLASSPATH so that hive server/cli/services can be started. btw, `hive.metastore.schema.verification` is about metastore schema verification, it's optional for this answer if you have a metastore DB with existing schema.

Comment: I installed Hive from the Apache foundation without hadoop. Because I will quit hadoop since its became not free.I would like to use hive metastore by PrestoSQL. 

But I got an error when I launch hive metastore:
Unable to determine HAdoop version information.
'hadoop version' returned:
ERROR: Cannot execute /usr/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh

Someone please can help please ?
I'm following these links

https://medium.com/@binfan_alluxio/running-presto-with-hive-metastore-on-a-laptop-in-10-minutes-72823f1ebf01
And
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are just talking about experiencing Hive before making a decision you can just use a preconfigured VM as @Maltram suggested (Hortonworks, Cloudera, IBM and others all offer such VMs)

What you should keep in mind that you will not be able to use Hive in production without Hadoop and HDFS so if it is a problem for you, you should consider alternatives to Hive

Answer (score 2):

You cant, just download Hive, and run:

```
./bin/hiveserver2                                                                                                                                        
Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path
```

Hadoop is like a core, and Hive need some library from it.

Comment: Right, I got the exact same thing. However, after download/extract hadoop core and setting up `$HADOOP_HOME`, hive can be started w/o HDFS since it needs metastore only when querying against data on S3

Comment: Yes you are right, but for me Hadoop != HDFS, HDFS is a more a component, like YARN / Tez etc...

Answer (score 2):

Top answer works for me. But need few more setups. I spend a quite some time search around to fix multiple problems until I finally set it up. Here I summarize the steps from scratch:

- Download hive, decompress it
- Download hadoop,  decompress it, put it in the same parent folder as hive
- Setup `hive-env.sh`

  ```sh
  $ cd hive/conf
  $ cp hive-env.sh.template hive-env.sh
  ```

  Add following environment in `hive-env.sh` (change path accordingly based
  on actual java/hadoop version)

  ```sh
  JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home
  export path=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$path
  export HADOOP_HOME=${bin}/../../hadoop-3.3.1
  ```
- setup `hive-site.xml`

  ```
  $ cd hive/conf
  $ cp hive-default.xml.template hive-site.xml
  ```

  Replace all the variable `${system:***}` with constant paths (Not sure why this is not recognized in my system).
  Set database path to local with following attributes (copied from top answer)

  ```
  <configuration>
      <property>
         <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name> 
         <value>false</value> 
      </property> 
     <property> 
      <!-- this should eventually be deprecated since the metastore should supply this --> 
        <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name> 
        <value>file:///tmp</value>
        <description></description> 
     </property>
     <property> 
        <name>fs.default.name</name> 
        <value>file:///tmp</value> 
     </property> 
    </configuration>
  ```
- setup `hive-log4j2.properties` (optional, good for troubleshooting)

  ```sh
  cp hive-log4j2.properties.template hive-log4j2.properties
  ```

  Replace all the variable `${sys:***}` to constant path
- Setup `metastore_db`
  If you directly run `hive`, when do any DDL, you will got error of:

  ```sh
  FAILED: HiveException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:MetaException(message:Hive metastore database is not initialized. Please use schematool (e.g. ./schematool -initSchema -dbType ...) to create the schema. If needed, don't forget to include the option to auto-create the underlying database in your JDBC connection string (e.g. ? createDatabaseIfNotExist=true for mysql))
  ```

  In that case we need to recreate metastore_db with following command

  ```
  $ cd hive/bin
  $ rm -rf metastore_db
  $ ./schematool -initSchema -dbType derby
  ```
- Start hive

  ```sh
  $ cd hive/bin
  $ ./hive
  ```

Now you should be able run hive on you local file system. One thing to note, the `metastore_db` will always be created on you current directory. If you start hive in a different directory, you need to recreate it again.

Comment: The dbtype could be "derby", because the database type script directory needs to exist here and the name may have changed in your version: I have 3.1.2

      `$HIVE_HOME/scripts/metastore/upgrade/`

Comment: With version Hive 3.1.2. the guava related error can be resolved by following https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-22915

`
$ rm /opt/shared/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/guava-19.0.jar

$ cp /opt/shared/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-27.0-jre.jar /opt/shared/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/
`

Answer (score 1):

**Update** *This answer is out-of-date* : with `Hive on Spark` it is no longer necessary to have `hdfs` support.

---

Hive requires hdfs and map/reduce so you will need them.  The other answer has some merit in the sense of recommending a *simple* / pre-configured means of getting all of the components there for you.

But the gist of it is: hive needs hadoop and m/r so in some degree you will need to deal with it.

Comment: Wrong, Hive can run without HDFS and map/reduce, there is a mode called "local"; Also, Hive can run against Tez engine instead of map/reduce.

Comment: @ThomasDecaux  Check your dates : this was written in Jan 2014. It is *no longer the case* that this restriction is in place. That makes your statement misleading without clarification.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is always difficult with SO answers

Comment: Hive needs hadoop libraries, and using hive to execute queries requires hadoop and map reduce.  But... can I install hadoop and not actually run it if I just want to use the hive metastore?  I was looking forward to using the "standalone" metastore in hive 3 but it doesn't play well with Presto yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Although, there are some details that you have to keep in mind it's completely normal to use Hive without HDFS. There are a few details one should keep in mind.

1. As a few commenters mentioned above you'll still need some .jar files from [hadoop common](https://apache.mirrors.tworzy.net/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.10.1/hadoop-2.10.1.tar.gz).
2. As of today(XII 2020) it's difficult to run Hive/hadoop3 pair. Use stable hadoop2 with Hive2.
3. Make sure POSIX permissions are set correctly, so your local hive can access warehouse and eventually derby database location.
4. Initialize your database by manual call to `schematool`

You can use `site.xml` file pointing to local POSIX filesystem, but you can also set those options in `HIVE_OPTS` environmen variable.
I covered that with examples of errors I've seen on my [blog post](https://funinit.wordpress.com/2020/12/08/how-to-start-apache-hive-without-hdfs/)