# "Cannot find hadoop installation : $HADOOP_HOME .. " getting this error while trying to run hive on spark.

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have followed this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started#HiveonSpark:GettingStarted-Configurationpropertydetails

Have executed:

> set spark.home=/location/to/sparkHome;
>
> set hive.execution.engine=spark;
>
> set spark.master= Spark-Master-URL

However, on running `./hive` i am getting the above error:-

> Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must
> be set or hadoop must be in the path

I do not have Hadoop installed, and want to run hive on top of spark running on standalone.
Is it mandatory that i need to have HADOOP set up to run hive over spark?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO hive cannot run without the hadoop.  There may be VM's which have pre installed everything. Hive will run on top of Hadoop. So First you need to install Hadoop and then you can try hive.

Please refer this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21339399/5756149.

Anyone Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: you are wrong,you can run hive with out hadoop if you creates warehouse on your local and give default fs as local both in hive-site.xml

Comment: @anubhav  By running hive in local it will not help to such big data and cannot move in production