# How to configure Hive metastore to use local filesytem instead of Derby?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, derby

I'm trying to steup a local hive instance, and want to use the local filesystem as both my metastore and my data warehouse. Is it possible to achieve that without using derby?

Following [How to use Hive without hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329856/how-to-use-hive-without-hadoop), I setup my hive-site.xml as shown:

```xml
<configuration>
      <property>
         <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
         <value>true</value>
      </property>   
      <property>
         <name>hive.metastore.metadb.dir</name>
         <value>file:///var/metastore/metadb/</value>
      </property>
      <property>
         <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name> 
         <value>false</value> 
      </property> 
     <property> 
        <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name> 
        <value>file:///var/metastore/metadb/</value>
        <description></description> 
     </property>
     <property> 
        <name>fs.default.name</name> 
        <value>file:///tmp</value> 
     </property> 
</configuration>
```

I expect that I should be able to run `hive` on my terminal without any problems, however I encounter the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Hive metastore database is not initialized. Please use schematool (e.g. ./schematool -initSchema -dbType ...) to create the schema. If needed, don't forget to include the option to auto-create the underlying database in your JDBC connection string (e.g. ?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true for mysql))
```

I am not using a JDBC metastore (i.e. derby), so why do I still need to use a JDBC connection string (as per the error messsage?). Is it even possible to run a local hive instance without derby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hive metastore process cannot use just a filesystem. It needs a relational database. The "Hive warehouse" is different, where internal, managed Hive tables are stored, and can be any Hadoop compatible fieleystem (such as local disk)

Derby is stored either in memory, or stored persistently on disk, but using Mysql or Postgres will allow for better performance

Note: Hive still requires Hadoop libraries, so "without Hadoop" isn't possible, even if you aren't using YARN or HDFS

Also, property `fs.default.name` has been deprecated and replaced by `fs.defaultFS` and must be in the core-site.xml, it's not a valid hive-site property

> I am not using a JDBC metastore (i.e. derby),

Yes, you are, via Hive default properties

`javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true`

Comment: Is the relational database strictly required for the CLI's functionality? If a spark job updates tables on a s3-hosted Hive warehouse, would the metastore still need to be a relational db?

Comment: The warehouse is the raw storage of the Hadoop FileSystem blocks. You have no other option for a metastore, so I don't understand the question, and has nothing to do with a CLI or Spark

Answer (score 2):

```
  <property>
     <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
     <value>true</value>
  </property>   
  <property>
     <name>hive.metastore.metadb.dir</name>
     <value>file:///var/metastore/metadb/</value>
  </property>
 <property> 
    <name>fs.default.name</name> 
    <value>file:///tmp</value> 
 </property>
```

settings are deprecated.

you can use local file directory to store hive data, but it goes through hadoop implementation, which means that you still need to install hadoop to use the local file system to store hive data. Here is the example on MacOS:

```
 <property> 
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name> 
    <value>file:///Users/<Your Username>/hive/data</value>
    <description></description> 
 </property>
```

it will use the directory '/Users//hive/data' to store your hive data.

Answer (score 0):

Metastore is the central repository of Apache Hive metadata. It stores metadata for Hive tables (like their schema and location) and partitions in a **relational database**.

So you need a RDBMS for it.

Databases Supported by Hive :
Derby 
MySQL
MS SQL Server
Oracle
Postgres